# Joomla - adding some custom text into the ratings box

Tags: joomla

We are using Joomla Version 1.5.13.
Where in the file system do I go to modify the ratings box to include some hyperlinked text, as below?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please upgrade to the latest version of Joomla for higher security and bug fixes. The is no reason to be using such an old version.

I assume you are using a plugin for the rating system in which case, please specify which one so others have a better idea of how to help.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Apologies for the lack of clarity. I assumed it was a plugin that shipped with Joomla. I may also suggest that the company upgrades to a newer version of Joomla.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I needed to open /plugins/content/vote.php.
At the bottom of the page is the rendering of the closing `</form>` tag. Insert new HTML below that.

```
...
        }
        $html .= '</form>';
        // Insert link text below
        $html .= '<a href="link.html">Hyperlinked Text Here</a>';
    }
    return $html;
}
```